# How should I pass NULL to the va_list function parameter?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, g++, variadic-functions

I wanna pass NULL to the 4th param of the following function:

```
bool CCMenuItemToggle::initWithTarget(CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector, CCMenuItem* item, **va_list args**);
```

like this:

```
CCMenuItemToggle::initWithTarget(this, menu_selector(GOSound::toggleButtonCallback), NULL, NULL);
```

It's ok when I build it in XCode (clang3.1). But when I port the code to android ndk (g++4.7), it fails to compile:

> no viable conversion from 'int' to 'va_list' (aka '__builtin_va_list')

How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume your code will work if you just use an empty `va_list` instead of NULL.

```
CCMenuItemToggle::initWithTarget( this, menu_selector(GOSound::toggleButtonCallback)
                                , NULL, va_list() );
```

Edit: 
Maybe this alternative solution works with both compilers.

```
va_list empty_va_list = va_list();
CCMenuItemToggle::initWithTarget( this, menu_selector(GOSound::toggleButtonCallback)
                                , NULL, empty_va_list );
```

Comment: I just notice that I tested your solution with ndk(clang3.1). When I switch back to ndk(g++4.7), it reports error:  `internal compiler error: in build_zero_init_1, at cp/init.c:280`

Comment: Well I don't think that I am responsible for that. The answer is still correct. The compiler is broken. Maybe it helps to declare a variable befor the call and pass the variable. See edit above.

Comment: This might be technically undefined behaviour due to passing an uninitialized variable?

Comment: @M.M I've added an intialization.

Comment: Second snippet in GCC 6.2: error: expected expression before ‘va_list’.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question was answered but it is not standard. the following code will through a runtime error in Visual Studios; however, it works fine with g++.

```
    va_list empty_va_list;
CCMenuItemToggle::initWithTarget( this, menu_selector(GOSound::toggleButtonCallback), NULL, empty_va_list );
```

A better solution would be to create a couple helper functions that construct an empty va_list.

```
va_list CCMenuItemToggle::createEmptyVa_list()
{
   return doCreateEmptyVa_list(0);
}

va_list CCMenuItemToggle::doCreateEmptyVa_list(int i,...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,i);
    return vl;
}
```

make the doCreateEmptyVa_list private and then when you call your function call

```
CCMenuItemToggle::initWithTarget( this, menu_selector(GOSound::toggleButtonCallback), NULL, CreateEmptyVa_list() );
```

Comment: This seems suspicious; `vl` will be "dangling" in a sense.

Comment: "Before a function that has initialized a va_list object with va_start returns, the va_end macro shall be invoked."
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass `NULL` as the fourth argument of your function. That function requires a `va_list` argument. `NULL` in general case is not a valid initializer for a `va_list` object. So, the answer to your question is: it is not possible.

How you should deal with it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: "what you are trying to do" here is: call the function.  The values of the other arguments determine that the `va_list` argument will never be used by the function.